# cpprestsdk segmentation fault in the task.wait()

Tags: c++, c++11, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to execute the `bingrequest.cpp` file provided by `cpprestsdk` library.

Here is source code of the file `bingrequest.cpp` ( [cpprestsdk github getstarted](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial))

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>

using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

    // Open stream to output file.
    pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile)
    {
        *fileStream = outFile;

        // Create http_client to send the request.
        http_client client(U("http://www.bing.com/"));

        // Build request URI and start the request.
        uri_builder builder(U("/search"));
        builder.append_query(U("q"), U("cpprestsdk github"));
        return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());
    })

    // Handle response headers arriving.
    .then([=](http_response response)
    {
        printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

        // Write response body into the file.
        return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
    })

    // Close the file stream.
    .then([=](size_t)
    {
        return fileStream->close();
    });

    // Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
    try
    {
        requestTask.wait();
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is :

```
add_executable(BingRequest bingrequest.cpp)
set(REST_LIBRARIES "-lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lcpprest")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -Wall -g")
target_link_libraries(BingRequest ${REST_LIBRARIES})
```

The source file compiles successfully in my system.

But it throws a segmentation fault. I used gdb and found that the program ran successfully before `requestTask.wait();` and it crashes after executing the above line.

Here is the backtrace from gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x85) at malloc.c:3103
#1  0x00005555556a582a in web::http::details::_http_response::~_http_response (this=0x7fffcc002700, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/cpprest/http_msg.h:474
#2  0x00005555556a5894 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<web::http::details::_http_response>::destroy<web::http::details::_http_response> (this=0x7fffcc002700, 
    __p=0x7fffcc002700) at /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:140
#3  0x00005555556a1c49 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<web::http::details::_http_response> >::destroy<web::http::details::_http_response> (__a=..., 
    __p=0x7fffcc002700) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:487
#4  0x000055555569bf9b in std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<web::http::details::_http_response, std::allocator<web::http::details::_http_response>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose (this=0x7fffcc0026f0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:535
#5  0x00007ffff7373b46 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#6  0x00007ffff7373cb6 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator=(std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#7  0x00007ffff736fec7 in web::http::client::details::request_context::complete_headers() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#8  0x00007ffff748f3ea in web::http::client::details::asio_context::read_headers() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#9  0x00007ffff74904ca in web::http::client::details::asio_context::handle_status_line(boost::system::error_code const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#10 0x00007ffff7478238 in boost::asio::detail::read_until_delim_string_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::allocator<char>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, web::http::client::details::asio_context, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<std::shared_ptr<web::http::client::details::asio_context> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#11 0x00007ffff7478a28 in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::read_until_delim_string_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::allocator<char>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, web::http::client::details::asio_context, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<std::shared_ptr<web::http::client::details::asio_context> >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > > >::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#12 0x00007ffff7468740 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#13 0x00007ffff73f06f5 in boost_asio_detail_posix_thread_function () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
#14 0x00007ffff66ae6db in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff1e92700) at pthread_create.c:463
#15 0x00007ffff69e788f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

The gdb output is not comprehensible to me (with respect to the `bingrequest.cpp` source file). Any ideas, why this segmentation fault occurs ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, Since this post has been over a couple of months now, can you tell me if this problem was solved? I am seeing same issue with cpprest 2.10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Is seems, that linking *debug* executable against *release* version of the `CppRestSDK` library is a pretty bad idea. Either compile library with `-g` flag, or remove it from the cmake configuration. This is also applies to windows build of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.then([=](pplx::task<http_response> task){
    try{
        auto response = task.get();
    }
    catch(const std::exception&)
    {
    }
});
```

Instead of

```
.then([=](http_response response)
{});
```

This works for me.